# How to make python script autocomplete filenames in terminal

Tags: python, bash, terminal, autocomplete, gnome-terminal

My python project contains basic script and some subscripts as follows:

```
project/
├── basic.py
└── subscripts/
    ├── firstscript.py
    ├── secondscript.py
    ├── thirdscript.py
    └── fourthscript.py
```

Project is used like this:

```
python basic.py nthscript -parameters -for -nth -script -here:"please"
```

(the `subscripts/` and `.py` parts are added to script path by basic.py) e.g.

```
python basic.py secondscript -stopafterchanges:6 -verbose
```

My current problem is that terminal can not autocomplete when I type:

```
project > python basic.py t[Tab]
```

because these scripts are in a subfolder. Is there any option how to allow terminal autocomplete `thirdscript` for example (above)?

Can I add some preference . (dot) file to my project, which helps terminal/bash autocomplete from some path? Or can I give my users some easy and clear manual how to set this on their machine (all of Linux, Windows, Mac) somehow?

Comment: Look here https://argcomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: For a nice bash completion intro/tutorial, see [here](https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1).